Why are the scrollbars in a custom control derived from TPresentedScrollbox not showing?
The following works for creating a TPresentedScrollBox at runtime and showing the scrollbars manually (setting custom content size):
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.ScrollBox;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FScrollBox: TPresentedScrollBox;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FScrollBox := TPresentedScrollBox.Create(nil);
  FScrollBox.Parent := Self; // this line seems to be needed for scrollbars to appear
  FScrollBox.Align := TAlignLayout.Client;
  FScrollBox.AutoCalculateContentSize := False;
  FScrollBox.ContentSize.Width := 1024;
  FScrollBox.ContentSize.Height := 1024;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FScrollBox.Free;
end;

end.


However, when I try to do the same in a custom control, the scrollbars never appear:
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  System.Classes,
  FMX.Types,
  FMX.ScrollBox;

type
  TFMXScrollBox = class(TPresentedScrollBox)
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

implementation

{ TFMXScrollBox }

constructor TFMXScrollBox.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  AutoCalculateContentSize := False;
  ContentSize.Width := 1024;
  ContentSize.Height := 1024;
end;

destructor TFMXScrollBox.Destroy;
begin
  inherited Destroy;
end;

end.

Instantiating it:
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.ScrollBox, Unit2;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FScrollBox: TFMXScrollBox;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FScrollBox := TFMXScrollBox.Create(nil);
  FScrollBox.Parent := Self;
  FScrollBox.Align := TAlignLayout.Client;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FScrollBox.Free;
end;

end.

The scrollbars no longer appear. I feel like it somehow relates to the parenting as in the very first code example omitting FScrollBox.Parent := Self; also prevents the scrollbars showing.
Any ideas as to what is going on here?
